# function php with while loop

Tags: php, function

Hello i am trying to make function with while loop in php but cant getting write here is my code

```
 function mail_detail($mail_detail){

    $data= mysql_query("select * from messages where messages.to = '$mail_detail' and to_viewed = 0 ORDER BY messages.id DESC");
    while ($result= mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    return $result;
    }

}
```

and out put is

```
$mail_detail= mail_detail($userid)
echo '<li class="read">

               <a href="#">
                 <span class="message">'. $mail_detail['title'].'</span>
                    <span class="time">
                       January 21, 2012
                   </span>
                                </a>
        </li>';
```

i am not getting all values just getting one value please help
thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `return` statement is terminating your loop and exiting the function.

To get all values, add them to an array in the loop, and then return the array. Like this:

```
$results = array();

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $results[] = $result;   
}

return $results;
```

on the side that receives the array

```
$msgArray = mail_detail($mail_detail);

foreach($msgArray as $msg) {
    //use $msg
}
```

To add on, a function is only able to return once (except for some special circumstances that you should not worry about). Therefore, the first time your function comes across a return statement, it returns the value and exits.

This functionality of `return` can often be used to your advantage. For example:

```
function doSomething($code = NULL) 
{
    if ($code === NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    //any code below this comment will only be reached if $code is not null
    // if it is null, the above returns statement will prevent control from reaching 
    // this point

    writeToDb($code);
}
```

Comment: i am trying to get all value from that table (messages), if return  is terminating what should i use in place of return so this function work with while loop .

Comment: thanks for help but its not working for some reason ... function mail_detail($mail_detail){
  
 $data= mysql_query("select * from messages where messages.to = '$mail_detail' and to_viewed = 0 ORDER BY messages.id DESC" );
 $results  = array();
 while ($result= mysql_fetch_array($data)){
 $results[] = $result;
    }
    return $results ;
 
} now i m getting no out put (

Comment: That's because on the other side where you are receiving the output, you are receiving an array. You need to iterate over it. You can't simply output it. Use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks Man it worked .... if u can update your mail post it will help others also ... thanks for help

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. What mail post?

Comment: how to out put this with Foreach loop

Comment: Here is what i am using `foreach ($mail_detail as $mail_detail_out) {
       echo '<li class="read">
                         
                             <a href="#">
                                    <span class="message">'. $mail_detail_out['title'].'</span>
                                    <span class="time">
                                        '. $mail_detail_out['created'].'
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>';}`

Answer (score 0):

```
function mail_detail($mail_detail){
    $returnArr = array();
    $data= mysql_query("select * from messages where messages.to = '$mail_detail' and to_viewed = 0 ORDER BY messages.id DESC");
    while ($result= mysql_fetch_array($data)){
        $returnArr[] = $result;
    }
    return $returnArr;

}
```

This way you return everything returned because you push it in one array and as your loop finishes, the whole array wil be returned. Because just like xbones said, a return breaks your loop!

Answer (score 0):

harinder,`Function(mysql_fetch_array($data))` return an array.  That means your `$result` is an array, so when you recevie the `$result` at view page you have to extract it using `foreach` look
like this:

```
foreach($result as $item)
 {
   echo $item->user(<-here you have to write the column name ,that you want to retrieve)
 }
```

Hence you can get your all results in array.