# Put MySQL data in a table using a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach, mysqli

I have a function which should get data from a MySQL database with prepared statements and put it in an array, and I have a piece of code which should get the data from that function and put it in a table. The two pieces of code are below.

*The function*

```
function list_students($connect) {

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT id,fullname,gender,dateofbirth,passed FROM students ORDER BY fullname ASC LIMIT 0, 20")) {
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $fullname, $gender, $dateofbirth, $passed);
}

$results = array();
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    $results['id'] = $id;
    $results['fullname'] = $fullname;
    $results['gender'] = $gender;
    $results['dateofbirth'] = $dateofbirth;
    $results['passed'] = $passed;
}

return $results;

}
```

*The code which should get data from the function*

```
<?php                       
$list = list_students($connect);
foreach($list as $variable) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><? echo $variable["id"]; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $variable["fullname"]; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $variable["gender"]; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $variable["dateofbirth"]; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $variable["passed"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

I can imagine I do something terribly wrong, because the data I get with this code is far from what's in the database. It's important to know that I have three rows in the table `student`, and the code above adds five rows to the table.

Can someone help me out with this, or put me in the right direction?

I hope I have explained it clear enough. If I didn't, please let me know so I can improve my question.

Cheers

EDIT:

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714394/function-php-with-while-loop), but `mysqli_prepare` doesn't support `fetch_array` as far as I know.

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. I've read that I need PHP 5.3.0 or higher if I want to use `get_result()`. I've tried using `bind_result` and `fetch` according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result), but that didn't return anything.

Comment: then you have to assemble your array manually. it is not that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! I used this as my function:

```
function beta_get_students() {
    include("config.php");

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT id,fullname,gender,dateofbirth,passed FROM students ORDER BY fullname ASC LIMIT 0, 20")) {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $meta = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
            $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_result"), $params);

        // returns a copy of a value
        $copy = create_function('$a', 'return $a;');

        $results = array();
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            // array_map will preserve keys when done here and this way
            $results[] = array_map($copy, $params);
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```

And this to put it in the table:

```
<?php
$list = beta_get_students();
foreach($list as $val) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="students.php?action=view&id=<? echo $val[0]; ?>"><? echo $val[0]; ?></a></td>
            <td><? echo $val[1]; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $val[2]; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $val[3]; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $val[4]; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I hope anyone finds this useful and many thanks for spending time reading this.

Cheers